# authenticate the user on Android but process on remote server?

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-api-java-client

I'm suppose to develop a new option for our Android app that allows new users to sign in with their **Google** account. We need to retrieve basic user info (First name, Last name, Date of birth, Email, Country etc.) and store them on server. It should happen only the first time user logs in to the app so the next time all the button is doing is simple authentication to access the member's area.

Currently, our app prompt for permission using `oauth2` and `AccountManager` and can retrieve the user info through [oauth2 api](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/oauth2/v2/oauth2.userinfo.get). I would like to do the same thing on our server instead.

So to sum it up here is the flow I'm thinking about:

1. User chooses to sign in with **Google**
2. If he hasn't authorized the app yet, request permission to access his info; retrieve and store them on the server and log in. If he has already authorize the app, simply log in.

We still need a local copy of user info on his android device though so he can view his own profile.

**Note:** The reason I'm thinking of doing the data import process on our server is to speed up the app and save some bandwidth. but I also feel that user might want to modify his data before they get saved to the server.

I'm really confused and the oauth2 documentation doesn't help much.

Comment: I think I have the same problem as you do. I would like my APK to get a token, send it to my server, and that then my server could check with Google if that token is active for the given gmail address...

Comment: I still haven't found any good solution or documentation on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

I don´t understand the problem. Sorry.

Just retrieve information about the customer from the OAuth api, send the information through HTTP/HTTPS post request to the server, save it there. Then save the same information in the SQLite database in phone and after first time when the app launches just check the user table in SQLite for if the customer exists.

Here is an awesome example: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Comment: what if the user logs in from another phone? or reinstalls the app?

Comment: Then customer will be logged into two or multiple phones. There you have to come up with technique to solve a problem. It´s a discussion problem. You can for ex. have GCM service, when user logs in from another phone the GCM registration id will change. Before you change id in your server you send a message to previous phone to delete user from SQLite. If the app is reinstalled then you promote user to login if they already have registered.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you need to follow the documentation for [Cross-Platform single sign-on](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in#cross-platform_single_sign_on) and [Cross-client Auth](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/CrossClientAuth) from Google. In essence, your flow should be:

1. Check to see if the user is authenticated (probably best as a POST to your remote system), if so, continue to your main activity. If not, show the sign on button.
2. Once the user clicks sign-on, connect the GoogleApiClient, retrieve the current person, save their information on the device (if needed).
3. Request an auth token for the user via [GoogleAuthUtil.getToken](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html#getToken%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).
4. Send the token to your web server (must be https). On your web server, retrieve the user's information from the token, and save it to the database.

Also, I suggest you use a persistent cookie store for your requests (I prefer loop4j's [Android Async-HttpClient](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)). This will allow you to save the session easily, so you do not have to authenticate too often.